# Show for $n$, $k$ $\in$ N, such that 1 $\leq k \leq n$, $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1} = \frac{1}{2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1} - \binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: summation, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

We are given a hint to show that both sides are equal to $\binom{2n}{n+1}$

For the right side, I have computed that

$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n+2}{n+1} - \binom{2n}{n}$$
$$=> \frac{(2n+2)!}{2((n+1)!)^2} - \frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$$
$$=> \frac{(2n)!}{n!^2} * \left [  \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{2(n+1)(n+1)} - 1\right ]$$
$$=> \frac{2n!}{(n!)^2}\left [ \frac{2n+1}{n+1} - \frac{n+1}{n+1}\right ]$$
$$=> \frac{2n!}{(n!)^2} * \frac{n}{n+1}$$
$$=> \frac{2n!}{n(n-1)!n!} * \frac{n}{n+1}$$
$$=> \frac{2n!}{n!(n+1)(n-1)!}$$
$$=> \frac{2n!}{(n-1)!(n+1)!}$$
$$=> \binom{2n}{n+1}$$

However, the left side is really giving me some trouble. I am not sure how to deal with the summation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645505/show-sum-i-1n-binomni-binomni-1-binom2nn-1?rq=1

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted an answer and then deleted it.  I deleted it because the analysis is virtually the same as one of the answers given in the MathSE problem linked in the comment of Kolja.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorial proof of a binomial coefficient summation: $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk \binom n{k-1} = \frac12\binom{2n+2}{n+1} - \binom{2n}n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11448/combinatorial-proof-of-a-binomial-coefficient-summation-sum-k-1n-binom-nk) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk-1%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cbinom%7B2n%2B2%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D-%5Cbinom%7B2n%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1). Note the RHS can also be simplified using ...

Comment: (cont.) [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule), along with $\binom{2n}{n+1}=\binom{2n}{2n-(n+1)}=\binom{2n}{n-1}$. This also then aligns the problem with [Show $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{i-1}=\binom{2n}{n-1}$](/q/645505) referenced in [Kolja's comment](/questions/4580552/show-for-n-k-in-n-such-that-1-leq-k-leq-n-sum-k-1n-binom#comment9642183_4580552). Also, there are other duplicates, e.g., [Proof of $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{n+1-k} = \binom{2n}{n+1}$ via induction](/q/2563509).

Comment: k is the index of summation so it should not be in the "Show for" part.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose n+1-k}
= [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^n \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} z^k
\\ = [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^n \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} z^k
= [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^n (1+z)^n
= [z^{n+1}] (1+z)^{2n}
\\ = {2n\choose n+1}.$$